# Making a digital clock in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make a built-in digital clock in a C program.

[image: Here is a sample photo]

This is the code I used:

```
int wmain(void) {

time_t t;
t = time(NULL);
struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
int m;
printf(" %d ", tm.tm_mday);
m = tm.tm_mon+1;
switch(m)
{
    case 1:
        printf("Jan, ");
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Feb, ");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Mar, ");
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Apr, ");
        break;
    case 5:
        printf("May, ");
        break;
    case 6:
        printf("June, ");
        break;
    case 7:
        printf("July, ");
        break;
    case 8:
        printf("Aug, ");
        break;
    case 9:
        printf("Sep, ");
        break;
    case 10:
        printf("Oct, ");
        break;
    case 11:
        printf("Nov, ");
        break;
    case 12:
        printf("Dec, ");
        break;
}
printf("%d", tm.tm_year+1900);
printf("\n ");
if(tm.tm_hour>=12)
{
    if(tm.tm_hour==12)
        printf("12");
    else
        printf("%d", tm.tm_hour-12);
    printf(":%d PM\n", tm.tm_min);
}
else
    printf("%d:%d AM", tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min);
//getch();
return 0;
}
```

The problem with this code is that you have to refresh every minute in order for the clock to update.

I have another code here:

```
void clock()
{
    int h = 2, m = 41, s = 12;
    int d = 1000;


    while(1){
        s++;
        if (s > 59){
            m++;
            s = 0;
        }
        if (m > 59){
            h++;
            m = 0;
        }
        if(h>12){
            h = 1;
        }

        printf("%02d : %02d : %02d", h, m, s);
        Sleep(d);
        system("cls");
        //menu();

    }
    printf("\n\n");

}
```

but this code goes into an infinite loop and doesn't display anything else but the clock.

So, how can I update the seconds in the clock without going into infinite loop?

Comment: You can use a seperate thread for the clock function and use a callback function to update your display from that thread. Or if you don't want to use a thread you need to look for the OS's clock and time events and implement a function for that event.

Comment: If you want to make a GUI in the console, the entire program will have to be in an infinite loop. You might want to look into [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) and not use `system()` calls.

Comment: I don't think that you can solve this problem properly using ISO C. You will have to revert to platform-specific functions. Therefore, please specify the platform that you are using (e.g. operating system, compiler).

Comment: "how can I update the seconds in the clock without going into infinite loop?" You can't... that's obvious. If you want a program to keep displaying the clock the program **must** run all the time. So the program must have an infinite loop. There is no magic here... (cont)

Comment: ... However, if your specific system allows you to install a timer based ISR that will emulate a situation where your program (ISR) only runs when needed (i.e. not an infinite loop) but that's not worth the trouble.

Comment: Never use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")` if there are some alternatives.

Comment: `wmain` could be much simpler if you use `strftime`.  It will zero pad the day of the month, but otherwise you can just use `char s[128];                                                               
        strftime(s, sizeof s, "%d %b, %Y", &tm);`

Comment: You can use a separate thread, but you can also learn how an event loop can process async events in one thread. That's how most GUIs are written.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI digclock()
{
    int h = 2, m = 41, s = 12;
     int d = 1000;


     while (1) {
         s++;
         if (s > 59) {
             m++;
             s = 0;
         }
         if (m > 59) {
             h++;
             m = 0;
         }
         if (h > 12) {
             h = 1;
         }

         printf("%02d : %02d : %02d", h, m, s);
         Sleep(d);
     }
     printf("\n\n");
     return;
}

void main()
{

    HANDLE clockThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, digclock, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (clockThread == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        printf("Error creating thread.\n");
    }

    while(1)
    {
        printf("main continue without block \n");
        Sleep(500);
    }
    return;
}
```

Try above code, basically your clock should be running in separate thread. create thread API may differ in your environment.

Comment: Ok I tried it and something weird happens. The clock keeps counting but it is scattered all over the console window...

Comment: pls add system("cls"), it was part of your actual code. are you using console for any other purpose?

Comment: no I just use it to run C programs on codeblocks

Comment: ok it is a little bit better now, but the problem is that it clears the entire console window. I want to display time on the top of the console window besides the main menu

Comment: assuming your main function is showing main menu, you need to take care of showing clock and main menu both inside main(). signal slot can help here fire user signal from digclock thread, handle it inside main and upon receiving the signal yo need to refresh console such that time is printed on top of main menu.